# How to access the audio files directly from raw/res folder using index

Tags: android, audio

I am trying  to develop an small app which will play the all the audio files available there in the raw/res folder using its index.

I am able to play an individual file.
In my program I have created three button next previous and pause on the click of next button next song shall be played,on the click of previous button previous song shall be played and on the click of pause button media player should be paused.

But I am not able to get the audio files by its index.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the resource ID with 
getResources().getIdentifier("FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION","raw", getPackageName());

InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier("FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION","raw", getPackageName()));